# graph-refactoring of an xml-graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to do a graph-refactoring to an xml-file which i imported into neo4j. For importing this xml you need this special apoc-library:
https://seafile.rlp.net/f/bf9fbe3cde30491ea26a/?dl=1

Then you can import a sample graph:

```
CALL apoc.xml.import('https://seafile.rlp.net/f/5db7bdc77c5447faad88/?dl=1', {createNextWorkRelationships: true}) yield node return node;
```

This modell shows an XML-Text in a graph. The text-nodes are connected with NEXT-edges and the serialization of the XML can be found following the NEXT-edges.

Now i want to find pairs of XmlTag-nodes with the _name-property 'lb' the connected XmlWord-nodes and then create a new line-node which is connected with G-FIRST_CHILD_OF- and G-LAST_CHILD_OF-edges to the first an and last Xml-Word-nodes of a line. The new G- in the edges-names is used to seperate them from the former edges.

Comment: Can you clarify that requirement a bit more? I can't quite grasp what it is you want to do with the empty elements from the chain. Could you also add what you've tried so far? And if you could supply some kind of pseudocode of what you want to do?

Comment: Tried to clarify the question. Hope its better now.

Comment: Okay, so is there only a single chain in your graph? Or multiple chains? If there are multiple chains, how are you finding the chain you want to perform this on, or do you want to do this will all the chains in your graph?

Comment: Another question, does each chain begin and end with an :element node? If not, what should be done with the start nodes of the chain before the first :element node, and likewise for the nodes of the chain after the last :element?

Comment: There can be multiple chains but all nodes of one chain have one special property in common. A chain must not start with that element. Nodes before and after the first and last element nodes can be left out.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. After the import, you have a new chain you want to process. How do you match to this chain so you only process it, and not the other chains you've already processed? Or, in other words, how do you find the start node for the chain?

Comment: Also, will you ever have consecutive :element nodes in the chain?

Comment: yes, could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a query that works in 3.2.x, but is failing in 3.3.x (will report this as a bug).

You need [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for this, as you'll need the split() procedure (for splitting around the element nodes in the nodes of the chain), the indexOf() procedure (for finding the indexes of the first and last element nodes so we can trim the node collection before splitting), and a conversion procedure to cast a value back to a node (cypher gets a bit confused when we use mixed-type collections).

```
// replace with however you match to the start node of a chain to process
match (start)
where size(()-->(start)) = 0

match path = (start)-[:NEXT*]->(end)
where not (end)-->()

// derive important collections of things from the path
with nodes(path) as nodes, 
     relationships(path) as rels, 
     [node in nodes(path) where node:element | node] as elements, 
     [node in nodes(path) where not node:element | node] as chain, 
     [node in nodes(path) | 
       case when node:element then false else node end] as splitColl

// trim splitColl so it starts and ends with false elements (our standins for :element nodes, as it makes it easier to split
with nodes, rels, elements, chain, splitColl, apoc.coll.indexOf(nodes, head(elements)) as firstElement, apoc.coll.indexOf(nodes, last(elements)) as lastElement
with rels, elements, chain, splitColl[firstElement..lastElement+1] as splitColl

// splits into groupings of nodes; each grouping will be surrounded by an :element
call apoc.coll.split(splitColl, false) yield value as group
with rels, elements, chain, apoc.convert.toNode(head(group)) as first, apoc.convert.toNode(last(group)) as second
create (el:element{type:'lb'})
create (el)-[:FIRST_CHILD]->(first)
create (el)-[:SECOND_CHILD]->(second)

// delete all relationships in the chain
with distinct rels, elements, chain
unwind rels as rel
delete rel

// create chain relationships only between non-element nodes
with distinct elements, chain
call apoc.nodes.link(chain, 'NEXT')

// delete the old elements
with distinct elements
unwind elements as el
detach delete el
```

And here is the test data I am testing with, using yours as a basis, but adding additional nodes in the chain for consecutive :element nodes, and for when :element nodes do not occur at the start and end of the chain:

```
create (:word{text:'Wort0'})-[:NEXT]->(e1:element {type:'lb'})-[:NEXT]->(w1:word {text:'Wort1'})-[:NEXT]->(w2:word {text:'Wort2'})-[:NEXT]->(w3:word {text:'Wort3'})-[:NEXT]->(w4:word {text:'Wort4'})-[:NEXT]->(w5:word {text:'Wort5'})-[:NEXT]->(e2:element {type:'lb'})-[:NEXT]->(:element{type:'lb'})-[:NEXT]->(w6:word {text:'Wort6'})-[:NEXT]->(w7:word {text:'Wort7'})-[:NEXT]->(w8:word {text:'Wort8'})-[:NEXT]->(e3:element {type:'lb'})-[:NEXT]->(:word{text:'Wort9'})
```

Given that this is a fairly complex query, you may also want to consider writing your own custom procedure to perform this kind of processing in Java, and call the procedure after you match to your start node.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work. I will clarify the question.

Comment: For getting your code work i had to add an lb-label to my XmlTag-lb-nodes: _MATCH (n:XmlTag {_name:'lb'}) SET n:lb;_ then i commented out the second line of your code and then it worked but it created many edges.

Comment: The idea on my query was to match on the starting node of the chain. Does your :XmlTag MATCH match to the start of the chain? And when you say it created many edges, do you mean extra edges, or just many edges in general? Remember, this wipes out your existing edges on the chain and recreates them.

Comment: The start-node of my graph is the Xml-Document-node. My problem is that _match path = (start:XmlDocument)-[:NEXT*]->(end) where not (end)-->() RETURN start;_ gives no result.

Comment: So this is either a problem with the label on the start node (please confirm this is the correct label in your graph), or your leaf nodes are only leaf nodes with respect to :NEXT relationships, and likely connect with other nodes using other relationships. Maybe try `where not (end)-[:NEXT]->()`.

Comment: I had to add a limit to the [:NEXT*]-edge: `match (start:XmlDocument) match path = (start)-[:NEXT*..2000]->(end)`. Then i get the path. Now i will try your query.

Comment: Ok you get the path with `match (start:XmlDocument)
match path = (start)-[:NEXT*..2000]->(end)
where not (end)-[:NEXT]->()
RETURN path;` 
Then i added a `element`-label to the XmlTag-nodes which have the property `_name='lb'` so that they get caught by your skript. But the result doesnt fit. I think my example data were to generalized as in my xml-import there can be other nodes between XmlTag- and XmlWord-nodes (Sorry for my complicated writing but I'm only a medieval historian). Do you think we can restart the question with my example above ( ... the import from seafile in the question)?